# Infinite series, Geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

If $S_n$ and $S_\infty$ denote respectively the sum of the first $n$ terms and the sum to infinity of the series $1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + \ldots$, find the least value of $n$ such that $|S_n − S_\infty| < 0.001$.

Comment: Please describe what you already know, so that a reasonably tailored answer can be provided.  As it stands, this is just a copy-and-paste job.  One thing to try is to compute $S_n$ for various $n$, and see what patterns leap out at you.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two well known formulas for starters:

$$S_\infty=1+r+r^2+r^3+\dots=\frac1{1-r}$$

$$S_n=1+r+r^2+r^3+\dots+r^n=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

Here we have $r=\frac12$.

$$S_\infty=1+r+r^2+r^3+\dots=\frac1{1-\frac12}=2$$

$$S_n=1+r+r^2+r^3+\dots+r^n=2-\left(\frac12\right)^n$$

Subtracting the two, we have

$$|S_\infty-S_n|=\left(\frac12\right)^n<0.001$$

$$n\ge\lceil\log_{1/2}(0.001)\rceil$$

$$n\ge10$$

Comment: Since $\log_{1/2}(0.001) \approx 9.96578428466$, $n \geq 10$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig My bad.  I saw 9.9 in my calculator and I rounded down instead of up...